Why are my getting a preflight/Option request between server to server POST request
Please I'm making a POST request from my web Server(Node.js) to another web Server(Php). Can it be possible for my Node.js Server to make a preflight/OPTION request to the other PHP web server if the content-type: is application/Jason in Axios?
var axios = require('axios');
var data = {"disco_name":disco,
  "amount": 1000,
  "meter_number": 2737373,
  "MeterType": PREPAID
}
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://datastationapi.com/api/billpayment/',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Token 3cd8882f7e5e92', 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};
axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});


What problem are you trying to solve?

Preflight requests are only made by browsers, not by axios running on a server.
